# C# cut file Name from Path

Tags: c#, path

I am creating an Image Extraction tool and I am able to retrieve the Images with full path..

For Example:

[image]

I need to cut the File name (rss) from path...

I search posts and Tried following

```
//1.
 //string str = s.Split('/', '.')[1];

//2.    
            string s1;

               // string fileName = "abc.123.txt";
                int fileExtPos = s.LastIndexOf(".");
                if (fileExtPos >= 0)
                    s1 = s.Substring(0, fileExtPos);


//3.
                //var filenames = String.Join(
                //    ", ",
                //    Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt")
                //       .Select(filename =>


//4.
                //           Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)));
```

None seems to be working

I want the name between "images" and "png" ..What can be the exact code?

Any Suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the class [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) and its method [GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s);
```

Warning: In this context (just the filename without extension and no arguments passed after the URL) the method works well, however this is not the case if you use other methods of the class like GetDirectoryName. In that context the slashes are reversed into Windows-style backslashes "\" and this could be an error for other parts of your program

Another solution, probably more WEB oriented is through the class Uri

```
Uri u = new Uri(s);
string file = u.Segments.Last().Split('.')[0];
```

but I find this a lot less intuitive and more error prone.

Comment: right .,. but with  a slight modification ...(in loop variable)string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s);

Comment: To whoever has downvoted: You are not helpful. If there is an error or a bad practice or whatever. You could help explaining the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you're using a uri so you should use `System.Uri`

```
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(s);
string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
string pathWithoutFilename = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Why use `Uri`? Because it will handle things like

```
http://foo.com/bar/file.png#notthis.png
http://foo.com/bar/file.png?key=notthis.png
http://foo.com/bar/file.png#moo/notthis.png
http://foo.com/bar/file.png?key=moo/notthis.png
http://foo.com/bar/file%2epng
```

Etc.

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2fffpS)

You should use the various [`System.IO.Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) functions to manipulate paths as they work cross platform. Similarly you should use the [`System.Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class to manipulate Uris as it will handle all the various kinds of edge cases like escaped characters, fragments, query strings, etc.

Comment: it displays **/images/rss.png** a output.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't finished. Try it now